# Pass the callback function as a parameter to wp_insert_post_data from inside a class

Tags: wordpress

I have class like this:

```
class A
{
    function __construct() {
        add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', [$this, 'my_func'], 99, 2);
    }

    //...
    function my_func($data, $postarr)
    {
        //I want to change some contents before save post, then i do:
        $data['post_content'] .= 'Add something';
        return $data;
    }
}
```

It looks like the parameters did not get passed in, so the function is not getting called. I also tested my code outside the class, and it worked fine.

How can I get it to work in my class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there - use `array()` instead of `[]`

```
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', array($this, 'my_func'), 99, 2);
```

Comment: @VănCaoTrần if you are dynamically passing an array into a function, you need to use this format. the `[]` shorthand works if you are assigning an array to a variable.

Comment: i understood. Thanks agian!